# Getting a list of DNS records for multiple domains

Tags: domain-name-system, a-record

We have over 250 domain names with one registrar which, due to years of organisational neglect, point to various different servers hosting the websites.

I've been asked to clean this up. *sigh*

To start off, I want to get a list of each domain name and their DNS A records to see which server they're pointing to. Does anybody know how I can go about this?

Comment: Put all the domains in a txt file, loop over them in your favorite scripting language... Done... (If you want more info, we need some more info. OS, Language...

Comment: We might be able to give you some shortcuts if you name the registrar. But any way you go, this is going to be one big unsightly mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it in PowerShell using a text file with one domain per line.

```
Get-Content domains.txt | %{
  new-object -type PSObject -property @{
    Domain=$_
    IPAddr=[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($_)
  }
}
```

Which outputs something like:

```
Domain                IPAddr
------                ------
www.google.com        {2001:4860:4001:803::1011, 74.125.224.145, 74.125.224....
www.yahoo.com         {2001:4998:c:401::c:9101, 2001:4998:c:401::c:9102, 200...
www.flickr.com        {216.115.107.206, 67.195.141.201, 67.195.141.200, 98.1...
www.serverfault.com   {64.34.119.12}
www.stackexchange.com {64.34.119.12}
```

Here's how I'd do it in Perl with the same text file.

```
perl -MSocket -nE 'chomp; say $_, " ", inet_ntoa "".gethostbyname $_;' domains.txt
```

Which outputs something like:

```
www.google.com 74.125.141.103
www.yahoo.com 72.30.38.140
www.flickr.com 216.115.107.206
www.serverfault.com 64.34.119.12
www.stackexchange.com 64.34.119.12
```

Comment: I used the PowerShell solution above and it produced the effect I wanted. Thanks, Starfish.

However, the script hangs after about a dozen domains, do you know of any reason why this would be? **Edit: Scrap that, if I hit return, the script continues.**

Answer (score 1):

An even easier answer is to get the DNS records from the registrar to see where they're pointing.  Most good bulk registrars have an export function just for this kind of thing. Now, if they're all being hosted off site, you might need to resort to the code to get A records for them.  But seeing that DNS resolution has been delegated to ns1.hosting.com will be a big clue to help you locate the appropriate hosting company and start working on obtaining credentials.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash:

Put your domains, one per line, in `domains.txt`.

```
for domain in $( cat domains.txt ); do host -ta $domain; done
```

That'll print something like:

```
stackoverflow.com has address 64.34.119.12
serverfault.com has address 64.34.119.12
```